# Can I disable uninstall confirmation message?

Tags: inno-setup

Basically the title says it all, can I skip `Are you sure...` message box part and run uninstall right away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message is not shown only if you run the uninstaller in silent or very silent mode. So only if you run uninstaller with `/SILENT` or `/VERYSILENT` command line parameters. If you're going to get rid of that message, you can create shortcuts with one of the mentioned parameters and optionally modify setup's registry key (e.g. `My Program_is1`) where you can append the parameter to the `UninstallString` key value. That will uninstall the application without this prompt even from control panel's applet.

Comment: For an implementation, see my answer to [Using {code:} in \[Messages\] section Inno Setup](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34126752/850848)

Comment: For more details, see also [Replace or customize modal uninstallation windows in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37023764/850848).