# Changing uninstall confirmation prompt

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to use code to change the messages in the `[Messages]` section?
I want to change the message `ConfirmUninstall` as shown below.

```
[Messages]
ConfirmUninstall=Are you sure you want to remove {code:GetIDandName} and its components.
```

Is it possible to do something like this? If not, is there a way that this could be achieved?

Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

No you cannot.

In some cases you might be able to use [a preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/).

But not in your situation.

You may automate the UI, but it's not nice. See [Inno Setup - Automatically submitting uninstall prompts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42259914/850848).

---

All you can do with `ConfirmUninstall` is:

- suppress it by forcing the [`/SILENT` switch](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=uninstcmdline) in an *Add/Remove programs* entry (add another custom switch to make it clear that it's actually not the silent mode) and
- implement your own prompt in the [`InitializeUninstall` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeUninstall).

```pascal
[Setup]
AppId=myprogram

[Code]

const
  UninstallKey =
    'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\' +
      '{#SetupSetting("AppId")}_is1';
  UninstallStringName = 'UninstallString';
  CustomUninstallPromptSwitch = '/CUSTOMUNINSTALLPROMPT';
  UninstallSwitches = '/SILENT ' + CustomUninstallPromptSwitch;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  S: string;
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    if not RegQueryStringValue(
             HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, ExpandConstant(UninstallKey),
             UninstallStringName, S) then
    begin
      Log(Format(
           'Cannot find %s in %s', [
           UninstallStringName, ExpandConstant(UninstallKey)]));
    end
      else
    begin
      Log(Format('%s is %s', [UninstallStringName, S]));
      S := S + ' ' + UninstallSwitches;
      if not RegWriteStringValue(
               HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, ExpandConstant(UninstallKey), 
               UninstallStringName, S) then
      begin
        Log(Format('Error writting %s', [UninstallStringName]));
      end
        else
      begin
        Log(Format('Written [%s] to %s', [S, UninstallStringName]));
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

function CmdLineParamExists(const Value: string): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  for I := 1 to ParamCount do
  begin
    if CompareText(ParamStr(I), Value) = 0 then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;

function GetIDandName: string;
begin
  Result := ...;
end;

function InitializeUninstall(): Boolean;
var
  Text: string;
begin
  Result := True;

  if CmdLineParamExists(CustomUninstallPromptSwitch) and UninstallSilent then
  begin
    Log('Custom uninstall prompt');
    Text := FmtMessage(SetupMessage(msgConfirmUninstall), [GetIDandName()]);
    Result := (MsgBox(Text, mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = IDYES);
  end;
end;
```

---

You can even go a step further and disallow the uninstaller to proceed, when not executed with the custom switch. This way you prevent the user from launching the `unins000.exe` from the installation folder manually.

```pascal
function InitializeUninstall(): Boolean;
var
  Text: string;
begin
  Result := True;

  if not CmdLineParamExists(CustomUninstallPromptSwitch) then
  begin
    MsgBox('Please go to Control Panel/Settings to uninstall this program.',
           mbError, MB_OK);
    Result := False;
  end
    else
  if UninstallSilent then
  begin
    Log('Custom uninstall prompt');
    Text := FmtMessage(SetupMessage(msgConfirmUninstall), [GetIDandName()]);
    Result := (MsgBox(Text, mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = IDYES);
  end;
end;
```