# Enable 'Close' button on uninstall modal window

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible in Inno Setup to enable or hide window close button at uninstall modal window?

[image]

The reason is that I'm using [VCL Style Inno](https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-plugins/wiki/Inno-Setup) to style my installer and in first uninstall modal window it uses active close button style when it's actually disabled.

[image]

Comment: No you cannot. All you can do is to implement your own version of the message. See my answer to [Using {code:} in \[Messages\] section Inno Setup](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34126752/850848).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl. Yes, I remember that, thank you.

Comment: What is generating the message box? Is it code that you have access to? Even if not, as long as you have the ability to run arbitrary code before and after, you can install a WH_CBT hook before showing the message box, then once the message box gets created, remove the WS_SYSMENU style, and finally remove the hook after the message box is dismissed. Can't give you any more details, it's been way too long since I built a custom Inno Setup routine.