# Automatically submitting Inno Setup uninstall prompts

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to hide the first and the last message of the uninstaller. This code works with a modified version of Inno Setup (Inno Setup Ultra 5.5.1.ee2) but does not work well to hide the first message (appears briefly and disappears):

```pascal
function FindWindowEx(
  Parent, Child: HWND; ClassName, WindowName: PansiChar): HWND;
  external 'FindWindowExA@user32.dll stdcall';

const
  BM_CLICK    = $00F5;
var
  Timer: TTimer;
  msg: string;
  Wnd, WndEx: HWND;

procedure OnTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Wnd:= FindWindowByWindowName(msg);
  if Wnd > 0 then
  begin
    WndEx:= FindWindowEx(Wnd, 0,'Button', '');
    if WndEx > 0 then
    begin
      PostMessage(WndEx, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
      Timer.Enabled:= False;
    end;
  end;
end;

function InitializeUninstall:boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  msg:= SetupMessage(msgUninstallAppFullTitle);
  StringChange(msg, '%1', '{#SetupSetting('AppName')}');
  OnTimer(nil);
  Timer:= TTimer.Create(nil);
  with Timer do
  begin
    OnTimer:= @OnTimer;
    Interval:= 1;
    Enabled:= True;
  end;
end;

procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  if CurUninstallStep=usPostUninstall then
  begin
    OnTimer(nil);
    Timer:= TTimer.Create(nil);
    with Timer do
    begin
      OnTimer:= @OnTimer;
      Interval:= 1;
      Enabled:= True;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

How to modify this code to work correctly with the current official version of Inno Setup and to correctly hide both messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First, I must say that I do not agree with this at all. But it's interesting problem anyway, and the implementation might be useful for other, more appropriate cases.*

*Also you cannot avoid the message to appear briefly. The solution automates the UI, so needs the UI to work. That's one of the reasons I do not like it.*

---

```pascal
[Setup]
AppName=My Program

[Code]

const
  BM_CLICK = $00F5;

function FindWindowEx(Parent, Child: HWND; ClassName, WindowName: string): HWND;
  external 'FindWindowExW@user32.dll stdcall';
function SetTimer(hWnd, nIDEvent, uElapse, lpTimerFunc: LongWord): LongWord;
  external 'SetTimer@User32.dll stdcall';
function KillTimer(hWnd, nIDEvent: LongWord): LongWord;
  external 'KillTimer@User32.dll stdcall';

var
  UpcomingMessage: string;  
  SubmitMessageTimer: LongWord;
  SubmitMessagePossible: Boolean;

procedure SubmitMessageProc(
  H: LongWord; Msg: LongWord; IdEvent: LongWord; Time: LongWord);
var
  WindowHandle, ButtonHandle: HWND;
begin
  { TODO: Cancel the timer, if the message does not appear within few seconds }
  WindowHandle := FindWindowByWindowName(UpcomingMessage);
  if WindowHandle > 0 then
  begin
    Log(Format('Found message window "%s"', [UpcomingMessage]));
    ButtonHandle := FindWindowEx(WindowHandle, 0, 'Button', '');
    if ButtonHandle > 0 then
    begin
      Log('Found button');
      PostMessage(ButtonHandle, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
      KillTimer(0, SubmitMessageTimer);
      SubmitMessageTimer := 0;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure SubmitUpcomingMessage(Msg: string);
begin
  if not SubmitMessagePossible then
  begin
    Log('Cannot submit message');
  end
    else
  begin
    if SubmitMessageTimer > 0 then
      KillTimer(0, SubmitMessageTimer);

    Log(Format('Want to automatically submit message "%s"', [Msg]));
    UpcomingMessage := Msg;
    SubmitMessageTimer := SetTimer(0, 0, 100, CreateCallback(@SubmitMessageProc));
  end;
end;

function FmtSetupMessageWithAppName(const ID: TSetupMessageID): string;
begin
  Result := FmtMessage(SetupMessage(ID), ['{#SetupSetting('AppName')}']);
end;

function InitializeUninstall:boolean;
begin
  Result := True;

  SubmitMessagePossible :=
    FileCopy(
      ExpandConstant('{app}\InnoCallback.dll'),
      ExpandConstant('{%TEMP}\InnoCallback.dll'), False);

  SubmitUpcomingMessage(FmtSetupMessageWithAppName(msgUninstallAppFullTitle));
end;

procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usPostUninstall then
  begin
    SubmitUpcomingMessage(FmtSetupMessageWithAppName(msgUninstallAppFullTitle));
  end;
end;
```

*For [`CreateCallback` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcallback), you need Inno Setup 6.*

*If you are stuck with Inno Setup 5, you can use `WrapCallback` function from [InnoTools InnoCallback](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=54) library (the code needs Unicode version of Inno Setup 5). But using an external DLL library from an uninstaller is tricky and has its drawbacks. See [Load external DLL for uninstall process in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36940506/850848).*

---

For a different approach to the problem, see [Changing uninstall confirmation prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34126752/850848).