# How to close finished Inno Setup installer after a certain time?

Tags: inno-setup

How to close the installer on the "Finished" page after a certain time?

It could also be interpreted as: how to close the installer after some time of non-activity? (close/cancel install). Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setup a timer once the "Finished" page displays to trigger the close.

```pascal
[Code]

function SetTimer(hWnd, nIDEvent, uElapse, lpTimerFunc: LongWord): LongWord;
  external 'SetTimer@User32.dll stdcall';
function KillTimer(hWnd, nIDEvent: LongWord): LongWord;
  external 'KillTimer@User32.dll stdcall';

var
  PageTimeoutTimer: LongWord;
  PageTimeout: Integer;

procedure UpdateFinishButton;
begin
  WizardForm.NextButton.Caption :=
    Format(SetupMessage(msgButtonFinish) + ' - %ds', [PageTimeout]);
end;  

procedure PageTimeoutProc(
  H: LongWord; Msg: LongWord; IdEvent: LongWord; Time: LongWord);
begin
  if PageTimeout > 1 then
  begin
    Dec(PageTimeout);
    UpdateFinishButton;
  end
    else
  begin
    WizardForm.NextButton.OnClick(WizardForm.NextButton);
  end;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
  begin
    PageTimeout := 10;
    UpdateFinishButton;
    PageTimeoutTimer := SetTimer(0, 0, 1000, CreateCallback(@PageTimeoutProc));
  end;
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
  begin
    KillTimer(0, PageTimeoutTimer);
    PageTimeoutTimer := 0;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

[image: Timeout of Finished page]

*For [`CreateCallback` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcallback), you need Inno Setup 6. If you are stuck with Inno Setup 5, you can use `WrapCallback` function from [InnoTools InnoCallback](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=54) library.*

---

Related questions:

- [MsgBox - Make unclickable OK Button and change to countdown - Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40446269/850848);
- [Inno Setup - Automatically submitting uninstall prompts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42259914/850848).