# How do I relocate the uninstaller for an Inno Setup?

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I'm installing a program on a secure operating system that doesn't allow the execution of programs from `Temp`. After some study on here, I've developed a working installer that runs the installer `OutputDir` from a special location we'll just call `Trusted`, which does allow execution from `Temp`.

After installing the program successfully, now the uninstaller is failing because it also wants to execute from `Temp`. After moving the uninstaller's `*.exe` and `*.dat` to `Trusted`, it works as expected, but I can't determine how to get the script to do this without moving the entire installation to `Trusted`.

Is it possible to relocate the uninstaller from the install directory in the Inno script?

Answer (score 0):

Implement a wrapper application or script that will move the uninstaller to the `Trusted` folder and run it from there.

At the end of the installation update the `UninstallString` in registry to make it run your app/script, instead of the uninstaller directly. For some example, see [Changing uninstall confirmation prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34126752/850848).

You make a simple C# app for that for example. Or you can make e.g. a simple VB/JScript.