# Replace or customize modal uninstallation windows in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, uninstallation, modal-window

Is it possible to replace next uninstalling modal windows with custom modal windows or pages in Inno Setup:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both messages are shown always, except for silent (or very silent) uninstallations.

What you can do:

- Change message texts:

  ```
  [Messages]
  ConfirmUninstall=Are you sure you want to completely remove %1 and all of its components?
  UninstalledAll=%1 was successfully removed from your computer.
  UninstalledMost=%1 uninstall complete.%n%nSome elements could not be removed. These can be removed manually.
  UninstalledAndNeedsRestart=To complete the uninstallation of %1, your computer must be restarted.%n%nWould you like to restart now?
  ```
- Get rid of the messages by making the uninstaller run silently always by adding the [`/SILENT` command-line switch](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=uninstcmdline) to the `UninstallString` registry key.  See also [Can I disable uninstall confirmation message?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16807226/850848)

  Though this is bit of a hack, and you better do it only, if you have a good reason.

  And optionally implementing your custom messages/dialogs by implementing [`InitializeUninstall`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeUninstall) and [`CurUninstallStepChanged(usDone)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurUninstallStepChanged), like:

  ```pascal
  procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
  var
    DoneForm: TSetupForm;
  begin
    if CurUninstallStep = usDone then
    begin
      DoneForm := CreateCustomForm;
      { populate the form here... }
      DoneForm.ShowModal;
    end;
  end;
  ```
- Another way to get rid of the message, when the uninstallation completes, is to handle `usPostUninstall` event and display your custom dialog box there. And forcefully abort the installer afterwards. But then the automatic restart of Windows, in case it's needed to complete the uninstallation, won't work.
- You can also implement some DLL that watches for new message boxes and updates/submits them as they appear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create custom pages in Uninstaller then No.

Uninstaller does NOT support creating custom pages.