# Is it possible to disable the successful uninstall dialog box with InnoSetup

Tags: dialog, inno-setup, disable

I'm trying to disable the successful uninstall dialog box with InnoSetup IDE.
I searched the InnoSetup Help, Web and Stackoverflow without finding answers.

Is there a flag for unactivate it ?

This is the screenshot dialog box :

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: See [Replace or customize modal uninstallation windows in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37023764/850848).

Comment: So if I well understand this thread, it's not possible to unactivate it ?

Comment: Looking at Innosetup help, it seems indeed to not be possible like Martin told it : http://unattended.sourceforge.net/InnoSetup_Switches_ExitCodes.html

Comment: Well, it's possible only with some drawbacks. I'd not recommend it.

Comment: Martin, can you describe these drawbacks please ? Is it using `/SILENT`, `/VERYSILENT` command line parameters ? Perhaps you could write an answer ?

Comment: The drawback is that uninstaller runs silently. This is not what users will expect. It may unpleasantly surprise them.